# Focus and required

Tags: html, css, focus, border, required

The problem is I have required inputs and I have some :focus on those same inputs when I try to send the values empty the border red from required show up and doenst disapear when I click on it so I have a wierd green border from focus and red border from required can some 1 help me to remove the required after click on the input

```css
    .form-login {
     width : 400px;
     height: auto;
     position : absolute;
     padding : 10px 25px;
     background-color: #ddd;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
     border: none;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    }
    .forminputs{
     width : 100%;
     position : relative;
     margin :25px auto;
    }
    .input {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     background:gray;
     position: relative;
     margin:15px auto;
    }
    input[type="text"],
    input[type="password"]{
     width:100%;
     height:50px;
     position: relative;
     outline :none;
     border:1px solid gray;
     border-radius: 3px;
     font-size:16px;
     font-family: 'Questrial',sans-serif;
     padding-left: 30px;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
                    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
           box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    }
    input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus{
     border:2px solid #50C878;
    }
    input[type="submit"]{
     position: relative;
     background-color:#50C878;
     width : 100px;
     height : 40px;
     font-family: 'Questrial',sans-serif;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: #FFF;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 17px;
     cursor: pointer;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 5px;
     float:right;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     margin-top:10px;
    }
```

```html
   <form class="form" name="form" method="post" action="login-m.php">
    <section class ="input">
     <input type="text" name="utilizador" value="" placeholder="Insira o nome de utilizador"  required/><br>
     <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </section>  
    <section class ="input"> 
     <input type="password" name="palavrachave" value="" placeholder="Insira a palavra-chave" required/><br>
     <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
    </section>
    <a href="#">Esqueceu a palavra-chave ?</a><br>
    <input type="submit" name ="entrar" value="Entrar"><br>
    <p> Nome de Utilizador e/ou<br> Palavra-chave incorreto(s)</p>
   </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried `input[required]:focus {}`? If you validation process adds classes to your inputs or their containers, have you tried using those selectors? Have you taken any step into fixing the problem, other than asking for help on [so]?

Comment: didnt work... dont know what to do

Comment: You need to learn how to inspect and determine what selectors apply the current rules on your elements. There's no way around that if you want to do this yourself. And if you don't provide a [mcve], we can't help you either.

Comment: what about same as @Andrei suggested but add !important to the end of each style. `input[required]:focus{border: 1px solid green !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution for your problem, but here is some helpful information.

You can use :required and :invalid selectors in CSS to change the styling on those objects. They can be chained with other selectors, eg, input:invalid:focus. This should let you modify the style and remove the double glowing border.

Comment: `:invalid` only works with [`Constraint validation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation). Currently most libraries don't use them for validation (because they're not cross-browser), but rather rely on custom classes added to the form elements.